# Refresh a WPF page from a child window

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

In `C#` `WPF` I have a window which hosts a page using `this.WorkingFrame.Navigate(Page1);`
Now on Page 1 I have a `listview`. On page 1 you can double click an item in the `listview` to open a new window (Page2) to edit the item.  Once the item is edited it is saved in to the `datacontext`.  Now the issue I am having, is once Page2 is closed, the `listview` is not updated.  Basically I have to navigate away from the page and back to it to get it to show the changes.  Is there a way to refresh Page1 from Page2 to show the changes made?
Here is my code

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //initiates the method to load data into the list view
        LoadLV();
    }
    //Loads data into the list view object
    public void LoadLV()
    {

        auroraDataEntities = new AuroraDataEntities();
        Data data = new Data();
        ObjectQuery<Inventory> inventories = auroraDataEntities.Inventories;
        //Returns only objects with a quantity greater than 0, so it won't show anything you are out of
        var fillList = from q in inventories
                       where q.Qty > 0
                       select q;
        ingListLV.ItemsSource = fillList.ToList();

     }
    //Method to open what I want to be the child window basically a popup Dialog box
    private void Open_Page2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page2 openPage2 = new Page2();
        openPage2.Show();

    }
}

    //This is the code for Page 2
public partial class Page2 : Window
{    


     public Page2()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        //ADDED a reference to Page1 in the constructor
        Page1 page1;
    }

    //Method when i click the close button on the page
    private void Close_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    //In here is the code that I want to use to refresh the listview on page 1
            //ADDED the call to the public method LoadLV on page 1
            page1.LoadLV()              
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look at using an observable collection if you use it correctly your ui will reflect changes automatically. Your changes would reflect in page 1 even before the dialog closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is even more general - views could possibly be arbitrarily complicated and the data modified somewhere should be invalidated/refreshed somewhere else. Suppose you don't just have two windows in a parent-child relation but a complicated nested views, with tabs or dynamic floating windows. Apparently, this is not just about "refresh parent from child".

So what is the possible approach to this? The answer is: **messaging**, the **publish-subsribe** pattern. You need an **Event Aggregator**, you have one in Prism4 for example. The aggregator lets your views subscribe to messages and publish messages.

The messaging architecture in your case is simple. You need an event, something like

```
public class BusinessEntityUpdatedEvent : CompositePresentationEvent
{
   public object Entity { get; set; }

   //or

   // if your entities share a common base class
   public EntityBase Entity { get; set; }   

   //or

   public justAnything ofAnyType { get; set; }
   public orEvenMore ofAnotherType { get; set; }
}
```

and then your parent view subscribes to that event and your child view publishes the event, passing the updated entity inside event parameters.

Once you get the idea of messaging between different areas of your application, your code becomes much less coupled, you stop to think in terms of "is there a connection between these two classes? a parent-child relation perhaps?" but rather you start to think in terms of "what message should flow from there to there?".

**Edit** A short term solution would be:

```
public class Page1
{ 
   private void OpenPage2()
   {
      Page2 p = new Page2( this );
      p.Show();
   }

   public void LoadLv() ...
}

public class Page2
{
   private Page1 page1;
   public Page2( Page1 page1 )
   {
      this.page1 = page1;
   }

   public void CloseButton()
   {
      this.page1.LoadLV();
   }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like it would be very helpful for what I want to do in the future, but since I am new to C# and WPF, I'm not sure where the code would go and what "JustAnything" should be set to, can you provide an example using my code?

Comment: The first property is an example - you pass the entity that was updated. At the subscriber side you have two options after catching the notification: either you just refresh the whole view (rebind the list) or you refresh just the element which is passed inside the notification.

Comment: Looking through this, what you are suggesting is way to complicated for what I need.  All I need is for page2 to refresh page1 when it closes

Comment: Let the constructor of `Page2` accept an instance of `Page1` so that the reference to the parent is available in the child. Then, just call a public method on the parent from within the child. This is as simple as that but it takes you nowhere, in a sense that sooner or later you WILL need messaging.

Comment: See above edits, I added it, but I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when it calls LoadLV.  Am I putting it in the wrong place? Did I misunderstand? Where exactly do these calls go?

Comment: You are doing it wrong, you are not passing the reference to parent into the child via the constructor. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your patience.  Its easier for me to learn by seeing it and following it through the code! I appreciate the help!!!

Comment: @MarkHomer: to realize that one needs a fishing rod, one must have gone fishing first. Sound then like he WILL realize that this approach doesn't really solve his problems, but first real problems have to occur.

Comment: @JoeK: glad I could help, however, I strongly encourage you to study how messaging works and how to make it into the core of your architecture.

Answer (score -1):

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

mainWindow.Closed += (s, eventarg) =>
{
    // Your method to update parent window
};

mainWindow.Show();
```

Comment: This answer to a 10 year old question, which already has an accepted answer has nothing to do with the question asked.